# I am unable to see the changes made in ui and API calls in react native projects in xcode.making the build no changes reflected fine with simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, react-native, ipa

I am building a application but when i am archiving and sharing the build the UI changes and API calls are not getting reflected in he ipa.Please share some solution for this . I am having macbook air 2021 model xcode version 13.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to Delete the Derived data & Clean Build Folder

Derived Data -> Xcode/preferences/locations
Clean Build Folder-> Product/Clean Build Folder